# Set the Global Arm Toolchain Path Programaticly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

develop an Eclipse RCP application, Inside the application is an GCC-Arm tool chain. I know I can set the Path to the tool chain in the preferences tab.

[toolchains Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka0Ry.png)

But is there also a way to do that programmatically?

Same for the Global Build Tools Path?

Comment: Note: One way to find out things like this is to use Plug-in Spy (Alt+Shift+F1) on the preference page to find out the class displaying the page and then read the source code.

Comment: couldnt find it in the source code

Comment: If the source code is not included in the CDT install you can always look at their github site which has everything - https://github.com/eclipse-cdt

Comment: I mean looking in the source code dint help me